# Best DE for system with no GPU acceleration

Tags: 14.10, cedarview

I have an Asus 1025c netbook(2x1,86Ghz processor, 2GB ram, Intel GMA3600). The GPU(PowerVR SGX545, I believe) is not supported for any acceleration tasks. I currently run Xubuntu 14.10, but I dislike XFCE. What DE relies least of all on hardware acceleration? RAM footprint is not very important.

Comment: Ubuntu is free so feel free to put any of them on an USB or DVD, install them and try yourself what feels the best to you :)

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm time and bandwith straved. Downloading multiple disributions and installing them on a painfully slow, mechnical hard drive is not realy an option. I'm looking for advice so I can replace xfce.

Comment: This is likely to be closed as primarily opinon based. To be honest, with the exception of Gnome / Unity, the choice of DE does not make much of a difference. Your computer is not going to run a big program such as firefox or libre office any faster or slower with any particular DE. You also need light weight apps. See http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/desktop-environments-ram-use/ - the RAM differences were, IMO trivial , with the exception of gnome, 100 mg out of 2 gb separate all the other DE

Comment: and your window managaer is not the only thing running, there are also various services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, MATE would be the best option. It is lightweight and at the same time, quite powerful with respect to the set of applications installed by default. The default window manager, Marco, does not use composting by default and therefore will give good performance on systems without hardware acceleration. Also, the upcoming releases will include an option to switch to Compiz for fancy desktop effects, although it is not recommended for less powerful systems.